# Why doesn't sourcing g:colors_name work in vim?

Tags: vim, color-scheme

I'm trying to make an autocmd that reloads the current color scheme whenever I switch buffers. At the moment I have `autocmd BufEnter * source '~/.vim/colors/' . g:colors_name . '.vim'` and it's not working. I get E185 can't find color scheme g:colors_name. Echoing g:colors_name brings up the name of the color scheme, and since that's the same as the filename, it should just be a matter of appending the path and extension, but something's not right here. What am I doing wrong?

Comment: I'm working with my own color schemes here, so I have complete control over everything.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

-- edit --

Your problem is that the variable is not expanded. Use this command instead:

```
autocmd BufEnter * execute "source ~/.vim/colors/" . g:colors_name . ".vim"
```

-- edit --

Anyway, why don't you simply do `colorscheme " . g:colors_name`?

When working on my colorschemes, I just do `:w | color apprentice` and repeat with the `<Up>` arrow.

Comment: Look at my question again. I have the .vim in there, I think you missed it. I'll try your second option and see if that works.

Comment: `autocmd BufEnter * colorscheme g:colors_name` also doesn't work. I'm baffled.

Comment: Also, in reply to your last paragraph, something about the way my color scheme is written makes it so that markdown files render strange, as well as HTML and a few other filetypes. I don't know what's up. The color scheme test in Vim works perfectly, and this autocmd solves the problem.

Comment: @Jonathan, can you share it?

Comment: Sure, here's the colorscheme. https://github.com/yramagicman/dotfiles/blob/master/.vim/colors/muttclone.vim

Here's my entire vim config (extensions/reg.vim isn't sourced by default):
https://github.com/yramagicman/dotfiles/tree/master/.vim/config